# How do I create a user that can create users in Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a user, granted all the privileges you can see in SQL Developer except sysdba and logged in as the new user, but I still cannot create other users.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Login as local sysdba;
2. Run:

   ```
   CREATE USER USERA IDENTIFIED BY "PWDpwd123" DEFAULT TABLESPACE TBS1
   TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP PROFILE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
   ```
3. Grant all privileges and roles you can see in SQL Developer to USERA;
4. Login as USERA;
5. Run:

   ```
    CREATE USER USERB IDENTIFIED BY "pwd321" DEFAULT TABLESPACE TBS2
    TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP PROFILE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
   ```

And then I get a `ORA-01031 ERROR`. What's wrong?
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to grant `CREATE USER` system priviege to that user.

```
GRANT CREATE USER to username;
```

You can also grant `ALTER USER` and `DROP USER` system privileges to this user.
See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm#i2077938

> **System Privilege Name: CREATE USER**
>
> Create users. This privilege also allows the creator to:
>
> Assign quotas on any tablespace. Set default and temporary
>   tablespaces. Assign a profile as part of a CREATE USER statement.

---

EDIT - practical example

---

```
C:\>sqlplus system as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat Jan 16 15:16:52 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create user test123 identified by test;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to test123;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create user to test123;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect test123
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create user alamakota1 identified by alamakota;

User created.

SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
TEST123

SQL>
```

The last command `SELECT user FROM dual` shows, that the current (logged) user is `user123`

Comment: Thanks! But would you please paste a link or show a practical code?

Comment: As you can see, I have granted any possible privileges to `USERA`. The code runs smoothly in 11g or older versions, so I doubt whether it has something to do with the Oracle version.

Comment: I've attached a log from a test session to the answer.

Comment: How can you create a user whose name does not begin with `C##`? I got an `ORA-65096` trying to do so. I am a complete newbee to Oracle with only a few MSSQL knowledges, so please help me.

Comment: I have a non-CDB installation (without a multitenant container database ). You have CDB installation, so all usernames have to start with `c##`, see the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503  In a non-CDB installation the username cannot begin with `c##`.

Comment: I'll try to reinstall Oracle. Thanks for your help!